# Inverse of a real matrix plus identity times i

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-numbers

How would you proof that given a real square matrix $A$ 
then the inverse of the matrix ( $A + i I $) exists?

Comment: Cheating: the claim is false. For example, take $\;A=-iI\;$ ...

Comment: Perhaps your matrix is supposed to be symmetric?

Comment: @DonAntonio: did you miss the "real"?

Comment: No, I didn't @RobertIsrael. I'm using "i" in the same sense the OP seems to be using it, meaning $\;i\in\Bbb R\;$ . If the OP meant $\;i=\sqrt{-1}\;$ then the claim's still false but my example doesn't work.

Comment: Unless it's being used as a "dummy variable", e.g. in a sum or product, the standard mathematical meaning of $i$ is $\sqrt{-1}$.  There's no $\sum$ or $\prod$ here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't necessarily exist. For instance, if

$$
A = \left(\begin{array}{cc}0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{array} \right)
$$
then
$$
A + iI = \left(\begin{array}{cc}i & 1 \\ -1 & i \end{array} \right)
$$
has determinant $i^2 + 1 = 0$.

There are conditions that you can place on $A$ to ensure $A + iI$ is invertible.

**HINT:** fill in the blank:"$A - \lambda I$ is non-invertible if and only if $\lambda$ is an ***_*__*_*** of $A$".

Comment: eigenvalue.. of course! Thank you very much